# HTML5 lining up in Firefox and Chrome but not at all in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

http://www.grossmag.com/2012/september/home.shtml

This link works in both Firefox and Chrome. I am not sure why it won't line up correctly in IE. I am trying to convert from old style tables/td's/tr's and this will be great if I can find out why it isn't lining up in explorer.

Comment: as well the accordion menu on the left does not seem to function correctly in IE

Comment: That's nice.  Did you have a question?

Comment: It seems to work fine in IE9 without compatibility mode turned on.  Are you trying to make it work for IE7?

Comment: im using ie9 it shows up with ecerything lined center straight up and down for me

Comment: You have compatibility mode turned on see my answer.

Comment: yes you are right I shut it off. So this will only work correctly in IE9 then

Comment: Probably will work in IE8 as well.

Comment: I see the compatibility mode being shut off fixed my accordion menu as well! Thanks for the help Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your site is being viewed in compatibility mode in IE.  This can depend on the DOCTYPE of your document.

To cause IE to display using the default mode of the current version, use the following META tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

This will not fix the site for IE7 (for example).  If you wish to do that, then you will likely need to create custom CSS rules for older browsers

Comment: Better yet have your web server send `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` as an HTTP header.